# Remove Element from a Hash Table

Tags: algorithm

I am studying Hash Table problems and I have one doubt about the delete operation in a linear probing problem. I need to remove the element 97 from the follow array

empty  37  97   50  49  38  empty  empty  empty  45  57   46

[image: Array Image]

When I delete the element '97' from my array I will need to resize the array or I can just remove the element?

This is my doubt because when (in one previous exercise) I need to rezise the array for double of their capacity since N >= M/2

**NEW DOUBT**

When I delete one element from a linear probing hash table like in the example just imagine if the h(49) = 3. But since 50 is in array[3] i will search for the next empty spot that is array[4]. I put it there. Then I will delete the element 50. Now I need to search for the element 49 and I know that h(49) = 3 but when I look at array[3] is a NULL value and the result says to me that the element 49 does not exists. How can I resolve this situation?

Comment: I do not know exact problem, but can be deleting done by setting it to empty?

Answer (score 0):

You'd typically not resize a hashtable array when removing elements, as there's "nothing" gained in terms of access speed by having a smaller array, but you'd waste quite some CPU time re-hashing the entries and copying them from the old to the new array.

Only when the array gets very sparse, for memory economy it **might** become worth investing the CPU time to reduce the memory footprint of the hashtable.

That's different from adding to the hashtable, where a too densely populated array makes access slower, as more often you have to use linear search after the direct hash-based access. So, when adding to a hashtable, you'd typically resize the array when reaching some load factor.